# Why are Java objects allocated in a heap?

Tags: java

Quoting Wikipedia 'A heap is a useful data structure when you need to remove the object with the highest (or lowest) priority'.

I am familiar with what a heap is and the kind of problems I can solve with them, but I was wondering why this data structure is the one used for the allocation of Objects in Java? Also, what determines the priority of an Object?

Comment: You're thinking about the data structure, but heap in this case simply means a memory store. It used to be called this because the memory blocks were organised by a heap datastructure.

Comment: You are confusing _a_ [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) and _the_ [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP). This is a [homonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym).

Comment: Oh wow, I though that the heap was a heap. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

The quoted text is referring to a kind of [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) called a heap.

The word heap is also used for a form of [dynamic memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP).

This is a case where one IT English word has taken on two different and independent meanings.  (This is a fairly common phenomenon in normal English ...)

---

> I was wondering why this data structure is the one used for the allocation of Objects in Java?

Simply, it isn't.  A dynamic memory heap (such as the Java heap) is not organized using a heap data structure.

In fact, the Java heap isn't really a data structure at all.  Rather it is an area of memory in which objects are allocated.  Space is reclaimed by tracing the *reachable* objects, and then deleting the remaining objects and consolidating the remaining space.

By contrast, a C or C++ heap cannot be traced and consolidated (because there is insufficient reliable type information to allow pointers to be identified unambiguously).  Therefore a C / C++ heap will include a data structure to organize the free space.  However, this isn't a heap data structure in the sense of the quoted text.  Typically it is an array of lists of "nodes" of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain that with a reference to C++.
You got local variables that get created on the stack when initializing the variable and destroyed when leaving the block. Basically that means that every local variable lives inside the stack frame of the block. Hence, dies the block, dies the variable.

If you don't know in advance how big your object is going to be, you have to allocate memory on the heap. An example would be a dynamically resizable array. In C++ this is done with the "new" operator (or malloc, calloc, realloc etc.). In Java you are doing this with the "new" operator too. That means you are responsible for creating and releasing the memory.

Objects on the heap don't just get destroyed when you leave a block. Except you define it in your main function and the program exits after that.
In C++ you either call delete or free() to free the created memory of your heap object. In Java on the other hand, the garbage collector does this for you. It is doing that by basically keeping a reference count to the instance (of course its a bit more complicated than that).